# if statement help windows batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like

```
if %a%==1&2 goto next

if NOT %a%==1&2 goto start

if %b%==1&2 goto next2

if NOT %b%==1&2 goto next
```

but I can't figure out how to use the if statement to check two variables in one and I could just do like

```
if %a%==1 goto next

if %a%==2 goto next

if NOT %a%==1 goto start

if NOT %a%==2 goto start
```

but that just looks really messy and isn't something I would like so please if someone can find me a solution I would like to see it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_nested_if_statements.htm They are called *nested* if statements

Comment: [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```bash
@echo off 

set "_a=3"

echo\%_a%|findstr /be [1-2] >nul && =;(
     goto Next
   );= || goto Start

:Start
echo\here I'm: Start
:: do something here 
goto :eof

:Next
echo\here I'm: Next
:: do something here 
goto :eof
```

---

To compare variable and variable b assuming actions `goto NextX` if equal 1 or 2 and/or different from that go to Start:

```bash
@echo off 

set "_a=3"
set "_b=2"

if "%_a%" == "1" (
     goto Next%_a%
    )else if "%_a%" == "2" (
     goto Next%_a%
    )else if "%_b%" == "1" (
     goto Next%_b%
    )else if "%_b%" == "2" (
     goto Next%_b%
    )else goto Start
   
:Start
echo\here I'm: Start
:: do something here 
goto :eof

:Next1
echo\here I'm: Next1
:: do something here 
goto :eof

:Next2
echo\here I'm: Next2
:: do something here 
goto :eof
```

---

- You can use `findstr "1 [or] 2" && (do) || do instead`:

```bash
findstr /Begin /End [range 1-2] and the operator for success && (
    does this 
   ) and the operator failure `||` does that
```

---

**Obs.:** This assumes your variable has value `1` or `2` or any other numerical digit, but if your variable contains one or more alphanumeric digits, then the `findSTR` would be:

---

```bash
@echo off 

set "_a=SomeStrings"

echo\%_a%|findstr /eb "SomeStrings OtherSomeStrings" >nul && =;(
     goto Next
   );= || goto Start

:Start
echo\here I'm: Start
:: do something here 
goto :eof

:Next
echo\here I'm: Next
:: do something here 
goto :eof
```

- You can use `if() else if () else ()`:

```bash
@echo off 

set "_a=3"

if "%a%" == "1" (
      goto Next
    ) else if "%a%" == "2" (
      goto next
    ) else goto Start
    
:Start
echo\here I'm: Start
:: do something here 
goto :eof

:Next
echo\here I'm: Next
:: do something here 
goto :eof
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`Goto :Label /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`If() Else If() Else() /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Read the comment I posted above. This is a super complicated workaround for something really easy

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks for your down multiples on my answers. Don't explain yourself, I don't care about your opinion. You're a new judge here, I'm a confessed defendant, that's fine. Keep it up.

Comment: @Gantendo **[Feel free and help yourself here.](https://superuser.com/users/969781/io-oi?tab=answers)**

Comment: I did downvote you on that other question, but not here. But I gotta admit; this probably works but it isn't a great solution. Not sure I understand your riddles.

Comment: @Gantendo So you're choosing what's easy and not on user-directed responses. So we have a good deed that validates any judgment.

Answer (score 0):

IF does not support more than one comparisons. For what you want, use something like this:

```
    @echo off
:start

::  -- Question the user    
    set /p a=What is A? 

    if %a%==1 goto next
    if %a%==2 goto next

    echo That was an invalid response. Can you try again?
    echo.
    goto start

:next
    echo A was 1 or 2.
    pause
```

Another option is to use the command choice, as it will ensure the user enters 1 or 2:

```
    @echo off

::  -- Question the user    
    choice /C 12 /M What is A? 

::  -- List these in descending order. 
::  -- They follow the order of items listed in choice. 
::  -- for example: choice /C YN, Y=1, N=2.
    if %errorlevel%==2 goto next
    if %errorlevel%==1 goto next



:next
    echo A was 1 or 2.
    pause
```

Comment: @Gantendo you posted this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_nested_if_statements.htm I assmume that's the link you refer to. It has many different ways to use IF. OP asks for a specific way, and what is explained in the link is the same as my answer here. So what was your first comment about below this answer then?

Comment: So the technique to make multiple IF statements that all have to be true is "chaining" em like that. `if %a%==5 if %b%==10 echo "The value of the variables are correct"` Both need to be true. But checking if a variable contains one of a bunch of possible values can be done as follows: `FOR %%a IN (1 2) DO IF %%a==%b% ECHO TRUE`

Comment: I've used || as \r\n: @ECHO OFF || SET /A b=1 || FOR %%a IN (1 2) DO IF %%a==%b% ECHO TRUE || PAUSE

Comment: @echo off || SET /A a = 5 || SET /A b = 10 || if %a%==5 if %b%==10 echo "The value of the variables are correct" || PAUSE

Comment: If I understand correctly, I was talking about doing multiple comparisons on multiple variables (x = 1, y = 2), and you were talking about doing multiple comparisons on the same variable (x = 0 OR 1) which was probably the cause of the confusion. No need for complicated workarounds, a one-liner is enough in both cases.

Comment: @Gantendo the problem here is that OP is not asking about a and b, but only a and a.

Comment: True, but what people ask is rarely what they want. I think we can agree on that.

Comment: So basically, your entire comment exchange is based on assuming that OP is not asking for something. Lets first ensure if that's the case before writing under answers that the answer is wrong.

Comment: That's not what I said.